# Сортировка многомерного ассоциативного массива по возрастанию значения ключа

Tags: php

У меня есть этот массив:

```
$arr['success'][] = array(

    "id"        => $out[$c_id],
    "nick"      => $out[$c_nick],
    "inv"       => $out[$c_inv]

);
```

Мне необходимо отсортировать по возрастанию вывод из "inv", как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Вы хотите `$arr['success']` отсортировать по возрастанию значения ключа `inv` ?

Comment: Alex, именно так и хочу сделать.

Comment: Покажите пример массива до и после. И код который вы пытались писать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function cmp ($ALeft, $Aright) {
  if ($ALeft['inv'] < $Aright['inv'])
    return -1;
  if ($ALeft['inv'] == $Aright['inv'])
    return 0;
  return 1;
}

usort($arr['success'], 'cmp');
```

Comment: downvote не изврацайтесь над языком.

Comment: @Naumov обоснуйте

Comment: https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/ru/coding-standard.coding-style.html psr-1, psr-2 вам в помощь...